# ExtJs Store Root

Tags: json, extjs

this is my JSON:

```
[{
    "ActionBy": "om",
    "ActionDate": "11\/26\/2013 8:50:56 AM",
    "ActionDetails": [{
        "Field": "St",
        "NewValue": "Clo",
        "OldValue": "Ch",
        "UpdateType": "Tie"
    }, {
    "Field": "AssignedTo",
    "NewValue": "mus",
    "OldValue": "n",
    "UpdateType": "As"
}]
```

And this my store:

```
historyStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
   fields: ['Field', 'NewValue', 'OldValue'],
   autoLoad: true,
   proxy: {
       type: 'ajax',
       url: url,
       reader: {
           type:'json',
           root:''
       }
   },
   listeners:{
     load:function(that,records,view){
   console.log(records);
   }
   },
   autoLoad: true
});
```

I want show Field, `NewValue` and `OldValue` in grid panel,
But it does not work Store, in my opinion, I am root problem.

Is it true JSON?
What I need to write to Root?

Answer (score 0):

Your json is not valid,
you can use [jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com) to validate your json.
 add '} ]' to your json to complete it.
give root value as ActionDetails so it will take data from that node, like

```
 root:'ActionDetails'
```

Answer (score 0):

> Your json should be like :

```
{
"ActionBy": "nimet.seyman@beqom.com",
"ActionDate": "11\/26\/2013 8:50:56 AM",
"ActionDetails": [
      {
        "Field": "State",
        "NewValue": "Closed",
        "OldValue": "Check",
        "UpdateType": "Ticket Update"
      }, 
      {
        "Field": "AssignedTo",
        "NewValue": "mustafa.arikci@beqom.com",
        "OldValue": "nimet.seyman@beqom.com",
        "UpdateType": "Assignment"
      }
   ]
}
```

If it is in this way :

```
 data =[{
    "ActionBy": "nimet.seyman@beqom.com",
    "ActionDate": "11\/26\/2013 8:50:56 AM",
    "ActionDetails": [
          {
            "Field": "State",
            "NewValue": "Closed",
            "OldValue": "Check",
            "UpdateType": "Ticket Update"
          }, 
          {
            "Field": "AssignedTo",
            "NewValue": "mustafa.arikci@beqom.com",
            "OldValue": "nimet.seyman@beqom.com",
            "UpdateType": "Assignment"
          }
    ]
 }]
```

Your store :

```
historyStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
               fields: ['Field', 'NewValue', 'OldValue'],
               autoLoad: true,
               proxy: {
                   type: 'ajax',
                   url: url,
                   reader: {
                       type:'json',
                       root:'ActionDetails'
                   }
               }
           });
```